# How to upload images only in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to Upload only images in asp.net(FileUploadControl) not only followed by Extension validation
because i found when Change the extension of any file with .jpg/.png it uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a prototype code that you can use

```
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
{
    string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName);

    if (extension == ".jpg")
    {
        FileUpload1.SaveAs("yourpath" + FileUpload1.FileName);

    }
    else
    {
    Response.Write("Only .Jpg allowed");
    }
}
```

You can add .PNG,.bmp also.. if u want

Comment: It will Check only Extension(.jpg/.Jif/...etc) but when i upload a Exel file with .jpg extension(Sheet1.jpg) then. Is it Actual Jpg file?

Comment: @ThakurDas it is a jpg file only.

Comment: Sorry Monika it is not working it will check only Extension but i need to upload only a valid file

Answer (score 0):

use ajax file upload..!!
then save the file name in the database..!!

could get the extension  "System.IO.Path.GetExtension(AsyncFileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)"

refer this link..!!

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-ASP.Net-AJAX-Control-Toolkits-AsyncFileUpload-Control.aspx